# How to get the View that hold a specific Drawable?

Tags: android, parent-child, android-drawable

It is possible to get the **View** that hold a specific **drawable** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible directly. What you can do is tag the `View`, using `view.setTag(...);`, with the `Drawable`'s name, or is res `int`, (`R.drawable.the_drawable`) value, and then use `findViewWithTag` to retrieve it.